# Get SP output parameter before reading rows

Tags: c#, t-sql

My underlying requirement is to know the total number of rows that will be output by a stored procedure before I begin looping through the resulting rows. This is being used in a data export, so as I loop through the rows I will be writing them to a file. The reason I want to get the total number of rows first is so that I can feedback to the user how far the export has gotten so far - eg "100 of 100000 rows have been exported".

The stored procedure is wrapped in a transaction and does some insert operations in addition to selecting the results to be written to file. The idea being that multiple exports should never contain the same record. That may not be particularly relevant, but I mention it just in case.

To solve this I have put the total rows into an output parameter. However when I attempt to read the output parameter in c# before the reader has been executed and closed then it gives me an exception - `object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Here is a simplified version of my SP:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    @TotalRows INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    -- do inserts
    -- rollback if there were errors

    -- select the data for the export
    SELECT ... 
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...

    UNION

    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY ...

    -- get the total rows (this works fine)
    SELECT @TotalRows = @@ROWCOUNT

    -- do some updates using the previous select results

    -- rollback if there were errors

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

And the code to try and get the totals before writing:

```
int totalRows = 0;
try
{
    using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(CONNSTRING))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SPName, db))
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalRows", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        db.Open();
        using (reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            totalRows = (int)cmd.Parameters["@TotalRows"].Value; // throws an exception

            int rowsProcessed = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                rowsProcessed++;
                // write export records to file

                // keep a log of rowsProcessed
            }
        }
        // if i retrieve cmd.Parameters["@TotalRows"].Value here then it works ok, but of course by this stage its too late
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle the exception
}
```

Can anyone suggest a solution? I do not want to run two queries in the SP - for starters because that would be inefficient, but mainly because this is all done within a transaction and so the queries might not give the same results.

Comment: I would suggest that your `TRANSACTION` contains only insert syntax.
Because TRANSACTION will cost more performance when it contain more thing.

Comment: The purpose of using `@TotalRows` is bit confusing to me. Do you want to get the number of records it selects by the `SELECT` query ?

Comment: Did you consider doing a `SELECT INTO`, then doing the count and the select at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a big query, the query itself is *still running* as you start to consume its results (if there's not enough space on the client to buffer all of the results)<sup>1</sup>.

The stored procedure is still executing this query and so hasn't yet moved on to assign the rowcount to the output parameter.

You *could* include a `COUNT(*) OVER ()` column in the result set but be aware that this *often* produces poor query plans, especially when dealing with a large query.

In the alternative, as Ezequiel suggested in the comments, you could dump the results into a temporary table of some form first so that you can obtain the count - but be aware that again, because this is a big query, you'll be consuming considerable resources just to be able to obtain this count.

---

<sup>1</sup>Every `SELECT` query is technically consumed by a cursor. By default, SQL Server uses a "firehose" cursor that tries to send its results to the client as fast as possible. But if the clients buffers are full, then pretty much by definition, that cursor has to suspend retrieving results until some of them are actually consumed by the client to free up buffer space.

Comment: Thanks. If as you say the query is still running as I loop through the results then it is fundamentally impossible to know the total rows until I get to the end.

Answer (score -1):

Might not solve your problem, but try changing:

```
SELECT @TotalRows = @@ROWCOUNT
```

to

```
SET @TotalRows = @@ROWCOUNT
```